# Aggregations Size makes different results

Tags: aggregation, elasticsearch

I have simples aggregation like

```
  "aggs": {
    "firm_aggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "experience.company_name.slug",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
```

and this gives me result like

```
 "aggregations": {
        "firm_aggregation": {
            "buckets": [
                ... (some others)
                {
                    "key": "freelancer",
                    "doc_count": 33
                },
```

but when I increase aggregation size to 2000 i get

```
"aggregations": {
    "firm_aggregation": {
        "buckets": [
            ... (some others)
            {
                "key": "freelancer",
                "doc_count": 35
            },
```

why is this happening ?? I thouht that size will increase number of aggregations which elastic return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is owing to the estimation done on shard level.
For results of size 5 , only top 5 terms are taken from each shard and this is added to get the result. This need not be very accurate.

There is a very good explanation about this [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts).

Along with size , you can pass shard_size parameter which can control this behavior without affecting the data that is returned